# html5 canvas - How do I determine the width of a character?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, font-size

I'm using `.fillText` with  fixed width font. I can set the height of the font by setting `.font`. but how can I determine the resulting width of a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try measureText("a") where a is the character you wish to measure. For fixed width font, it should all be the same.